# React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies Either include them or remove the dependency array react-hooks/exhaustive-deps

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have this alert on console:

**React Hook useEffect has missing dependencies: 'clearClient', 'clearProductEdit', 'clearProducts', 'client', 'productEdit', and 'rows'. Either include them or remove the dependency array  react-hooks/exhaustive-deps**

clearClient,ClearProducts and clearProductsEdit are similar functions, which return the initial value of my reducer

The function is working normally, however I would like to resolve this alert, am I using useEffect incorrectly? How can I solve this?

My useEffect:

```
useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            clearClient(client)
            clearProducts(rows)
            clearProductEdit(productEdit)
        }
    }, [])
```

My clearClient function:

```
  function clearClient(c) {
        dispatch({
            type: 'CLEAR_CLIENT',
            payload: { row: c },
        })
    }
```

On my reducer,the initialState is:

```
const initialState = {
    client: {
        name: '',
        id: '',
        dateBirth: '',
        cpf: '',
        address: {
            street: '',
            number: '',
            district: '',
            city: '',
            cep: '',
            uf: '',
            complement:'',
            phone: '',
        },
    },
}
```

And the case of CLEAR_CLIENT:

```
 case 'CLEAR_CLIENT':
            return {
                ...state,
                client: {
                    name: '',
                    id: '',
                    dateBirth: '',
                    cpf: '',
                    address: {
                        street: '',
                        number: '',
                        district: '',
                        city: '',
                        cep: '',
                        uf: '',
                        complement:'',
                        phone: '',
                    },
                },
            }
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to fix missing dependency warning when using useEffect React Hook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55840294/how-to-fix-missing-dependency-warning-when-using-useeffect-react-hook)

Comment: No,it doesn't, the question is sent me is about a fetch,i'm using react-redux useDispatch hook

Comment: @lawrence-witt The question you sent is wrapping the fetch inside use effect, this is fine on the situation demonstrated there, but here we have a hook, you cannot use useDispatch(i assume the OP is using it) inside functions, only components, the solution i gave answers better the issue than the link you sent

Comment: Yes,i am using useDispatch from react-redux

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend you to use the store variable outside the React component, like this

```
    useEffect(() => {
        return () => {
            store.dispatch({
                type: 'CLEAR_CLIENT'
            })

            store.dispatch({
                type: 'CLEAR_PRODUCTS'
            })

            store.dispatch({
                type: 'CLEAR_PRODUCTS_EDIT'
            })
        }
    }, [])
```

As you are cleaning the store, you don't need to send payload, feel free to change the type namings to the ones you use on your code.

Comment: didn't know hooks inside useEffect caused this alert, your solution worked, thanks!